# What spells are available to teleport willing characters?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, teleportation

**What are the official spells (published materials only) that can be used by characters to teleport both themselves and others in Fifth edition Dungeons & Dragons?**

Which classes can cast them and at what level? If appropriate, what is the limit to the distance that can be teleported using them? How many companions can accompany the caster? Are they limited to teleportation within a single plane, or not?

I am not interested in spells that can only teleport the caster (without companions), or spells that primarily exist to teleport unwilling creatures (ie. Banish).

Comment: [Vortex Warp](http://dnd5e.wikidot.com/spell:vortex-warp) is an newer 2nd level spell that doesn't quite meet your requirements. It can teleport one other creature, but not the caster, over a short distance. It is useful for repositioning willing allies, and unwilling creatures (if they fail a CON save).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

| Name | Level | Classes | Companions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Thunder Step | 3rd | Sorcerer, Warlock, Wizard | 1 |
| Dimension Door | 4th | Bard, Sorcerer, Warlock, Wizard | 1 |
| Teleportation Circle | 5th | Bard, Sorcerer, Wizard | no limit |
| Arcane Gate | 6th | Sorcerer, Warlock, Wizard | no limit |
| Transport via Plants | 6th | Druid | no limit |
| Word of Recall | 6th | Cleric | 4 |
| Teleport | 7th | Bard, Sorcerer, Wizard | 8 |
| Plane Shift | 7th | Cleric, Druid, Sorcerer, Warlock, Wizard | 8 |
| Gate | 9th | Cleric, Sorcerer, Wizard | no limit |

In detail (all page references are from the PHB, unless otherwise stated):

**Thunder Step**: 3rd level Conjuration spell, minimum 5th level caster, (Sorcerer, Warlock, Wizard). *XGtE*, pg. 168.
*90 ft range. Up to 2 creatures. Same plane only. Note that it also deals damage around you as you leave, so have any companions not brought along clear the area*

**Dimension Door:**  4th level Conjuration spell, minimum 7th level caster (Bard, Sorcerer, Warlock, Wizard) p. 233
*500 ft range. Up to 2 creatures. Same plane only*

**Teleportation Circle:** 5th level Conjuration spell, minimum 9th level caster (Bard, Sorcerer, Wizard) p. 282
*Unlimited range, requires teleportation circle sequence. As many people can pass through it before it closes. Same plane only.*

**Arcane Gate:** 6th level Conjuration spell, minimum 11th level caster (Sorcerer, Warlock, Wizard) p. 214
*500 ft range. As many people can pass through it. Same plane only.*

**Transport via Plants:** 6th level Conjuration spell, minimum 11th level caster (Druid) p. 283
*Unlimited range. As many people can pass through it before it ends. Same plane only.*

**Word of Recall:** 6th level Conjuration spell, minimum 11th level caster (Cleric) p. 289
*Unlimited range, must have a designated sanctuary. Up to 5 creatures. Possibly allows travel between planes if you are in a different plane than your sanctuary.*

**Teleport:** 7th level Conjuration spell, minimum 13th level caster (Bard, Sorcerer, Wizard) p. 281
*Unlimited range. Up to 9 (You + 8) creatures. Same plane only.*

**Plane Shift:** 7th level Conjuration spell, minimum 13th level caster (Cleric, Druid, Sorcerer, Warlock, Wizard) p. 266
*Unlimited range. Up to 9 (You + 8) willing creatures. Allows travel to different planes.*

**Gate:** 9th level Conjuration spell, minimum 17th level caster (Cleric, Sorcerer, Wizard) p. 244
*Unlimited range. As many people can pass through it before it closes. Allows travel to different planes.*

---

Page references for [SRD V 5.1](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf) (Arcane Gate is not included in the SRD):
Dimension Door p. 135; Teleportation Circle p. 186; Transport via Plants p. 188; Word of Recall p. 193; Teleport p. 185; Plane Shift p. 168; Gate p. 148

Comment: Astral Projection also enables the teleportation of a large group of creatures if you enter a planar gate while astral projecting. (PHB)

Comment: While not technicaly a spell, *Benign Transposition* of Wizard's School of Conjuration Arcance Tradition allows to swap places with a willing creature.

Comment: Might be worth clarifying that Plane Shift and Gate only allow travel to other planes, and don't allow travel within a plane (other than by casting them twice).